# Eigenvector of transition matrix for Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Why is the only eigenvector of the transition matrix for an irreducible Markov chain
with eigenvalue $= 1$ the eigenvector with all ones?

Comment: Is it clear to you why the vector of all ones is an eigenvector and why it corresponds to the eigenvalue of 1? Assuming you've got that I think Did's response below explains why there is no other eigenvector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otherwise the transition matrix would have two linearly independent eigenvectors on the right for the eigenvalue $1$, hence it would also have two linearly independent eigenvectors $\pi$ and $\varrho$ on the left for the eigenvalue $1$, the eigenvector $\pi$, say,  being a stationary distribution. Irreducibility would then ensure that every component of $\pi$ is positive hence some linear combination of $\pi$ and $\varrho$ would also be a stationary distribution, in contradiction with the uniqueness of the stationary distribution.